# What is the typical ratio of downloads to sign ups for B2C product apps eg A typical fitness/health app?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, signup-signon

I have a health app where the user sign up is quite straightforward(at least in my eyes). It goes as follows -

1. Screen 1 - enter email id, password
2. Screen 2 - enter verification code sent on email
3. Screen 3 - enter Name, gender

Currently the average ratio of downloads to sign ups has been around **65%** only. So around **35%** of the people who download don't go through sign up process at all. Is this normal for a typical b2c app like ours?
What can I do to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find numbers on your specific topic (b2c fitness health app, conversion download-signup), but here are some numbers to get a better feel for the order of magnitude.

In [this blog post](https://heap.io/blog/data-stories/good-conversion-rate-signup-flow) they mention a conversion rate of 36.2% based on 79 SaaS companies for the signup flow on a website. This might not be comparable as your users have already downloaded the app.
This [article](https://www.apptweak.com/aso-blog/average-app-conversion-rate-per-category-2019) mentions a 32.7% conversion rate from app page to download for health&fitness apps.

How can you improve this? Find out why people drop out either by asking them directly or looking at data.
Maybe:

- They wanted to use it right away and don't have time to signup
- They quit because they forgot the login to their email account
- They don't want to disclose sensitive personal information (name, email, gender) with the app
- Your password restrictions are too strong
- Your app has performance problems on their phone

Comment: It would be useful to know which screen they get as far as (1,2,3)